# Angularjs : $locationChangeStart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, token

i'm try to check token next  in `next`  but i'm getting error :

```
TypeError: next.localStorage is not a function
```

**APP.JS**

```
.run(function ($rootScope, $location,$log,User) {

     $rootScope.$on("$locationChangeStart", function (event,next, current,jwtHelper) {

         if(next.localStorage("id_token")){

              console.log("true");

         }else{

             console.log("false");
         }
         /* 

    });
```

Comment: Regardless of arguments....localStorage is a window object and you don't call it directly as function. Why do you think that `next` should have localStorage property that is a function in the first place? Is there something in your route config for that?

Answer (score 0):

The AngularJS documentation shows the second parameter "newUrl" as a string.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location

> **angularEvent**: Object. Synthetic event object.
>
> **newUrl**: string. New URL
>
> **oldUrl**: string (optional). URL that was before it was changed.
>
> **newState**: string (optional). New history state object
>
> **oldState**: string (optional). History state object that was before it
>   was changed.

Your code is trying to do something like this:

```
if("http://www.app.com/path".localStorage("id_token")){
```

localStorage is a window object and should be shared across all pages so you can access it with:

```
if(window.localStorage.getItem("id_token")){
```

Comment: should be `localStorage.getItem("id_token")` or `localStorage.id_token`